# Ruby on Rails Cart error "ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy"

Tags: activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

i am currently trying to build eCommerce site with ruby on rails 5. I have built a store page and button that adds product to the cart, however the cart shows "#" instead of product description or product that was selected.

[image]

This is what it looks like, after selecting an item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your view file, instead of printing `object`, you should print `object.name` or `object.description`.

PS: It is always recommended to post code snippet while asking question on Stack Overflow. This will give us opportunity to look at your code and point out any specific modifications